# On the conditions of convergence in the generalized Riemann-Lebesgue lemma

Tags: fourier-analysis, integration

I am reposting the following question that I asked in the MSE site [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4713995/121671).

As I mentioned there, The following generalizations of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma are rather well known (Kahane, C. S., *Generalizations of the Riemann-Lebesgue and Cantor-Lebesgue lemmas*, Czechoslovak Mathematical Journal, Vol 30 (1980), No. 1, 108-117):

> **Theorem I:** Suppose $g\in L_\infty([0,\infty),m)$. A necessary and sufficient condition for
> \begin{align}
> I(f; g):=\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\int^\infty_0 f(t) g(\lambda t)\,dt\tag{0}\label{zero}
> \end{align}
> to exists for every $f\in L_1([0,\infty),m)$ is that $g$ has the mean value property, i.e.
> \begin{align}
> I(g)=\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac1T\int^T_0 g(t)\,dt\tag{1}\label{one}
> \end{align}
> exists. Furthermore, when this is the case,
> \begin{align}
> I(f; g)=\Big(\int^\infty_0 f(t)\,dt\Big) I(g)\tag{2}\label{two}
> \end{align}

This results extends easily to  $L_1(\mathbb{R},m)$ as follows:

> **Corollary I:** Suppose $g\in L_\infty(\mathbb{R},m)$. A necessary and sufficient condition for
> \begin{align}
> I(f; g):=\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\int_\mathbb{R} f(t) g(\lambda t)\,dt\tag{3}\label{three}
> \end{align}
> to exists for every $f\in L_1(\mathbb{R},m)$ is that $g_-(t)=g(-t)\mathbb{1}_{[0,\infty)}(t)$  and $g_+(t)=g(t)\mathbb{1}_{[0,\infty)}(t)$ have the mean value property.  If  this is the case,
> \begin{align}
> I(f; g)=\Big(\int^0_{-\infty} f(t)\,dt\Big) I(g_-) + \Big(\int^\infty_0 f(t)\,dt\Big) I(g_+)\tag{4}\label{four}
> \end{align}

Perhaps the  most common version of  these results is the case where $g\in L_\infty(\mathbb{R},m)$ and  $g$ is  $P$-periodic function ($g(x+P)=g(x)$ for all $x$ and some $P>0$). Then  \eqref{four} has the form
\begin{align}
\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t)g(\lambda t)\,dt=\Big(\frac{1}{P}\int^P_0 g(t)\,dt\Big)\int_\mathbb{R} f(t)\,dt\tag{5}\label{five}
\end{align}

The assumption that $g\in L_\infty(\mathbb{R},m)$ can be relaxed by considering integrals over finite intervals and some duality assumptions:

> Theorem II: Suppose $g\in L^{loc}_q([0,\infty),m)$ , $q>1$, and let $0\leq a< b<\infty$. For the limit
> \begin{align}
>  I(f; g,[a,b]):=\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\int^b_a f(t) g(\lambda t)\,dt\tag{6}\label{six}
> \end{align}
> to exists for every $f\in L_p([a,b],m)$, $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$, it is necessary and sufficient that
>
> - (i) $\frac1T\int^T_0|g(t)|^q\,dt=O(1)$ as $T\rightarrow\infty$,
> - (ii) $g$ has the mean value property \eqref{one}.
>
> If (i) and (ii) hold, then the limit \eqref{six} takes the form
> \begin{align}
> I(f; g, [a,b])=\Big(\int^b_a f(t)\,dt\Big) I(g)\tag{7}\label{seven}
> \end{align}

The validity of the results presented above is based on duality between $L_p$ spaces.  Holder's inequality provides uniform bounds on some linear operators,  uniform boundedness principle and density arguments then give the desired results.

---

***Question:***
I would like to know if there is a counter example to Theorem I if the assumption $g\in L_\infty([0,\infty),m)$ is relaxed while maintaining the integrability assumption for $f$. To be more precise and to simplify matters,

Are there measurable functions $g$ and $f$, such that,

- $g$ is $1$-periodic, $g\in L_1([0,1],m)\setminus  L_\infty([0,1],m)$,
- $f\in L_1(\mathbb{R},m)$
- for any $\lambda>0$, $t\mapsto f(t) g(\lambda t)\in L_1(\mathbb{R},m),$

but either $I(f; g)=\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\int^\infty_0 f(t) g(t\lambda)\,dt$ does not exists (as a real number), or if it does, $I(f; g)\neq I(g) \int^\infty_0 f$.

If any body knowns a counter example or may be able to build one, that would also be fantastic!